# As expressões "uma seca" e "um saco" são relacionadas?

Tags: etimologia, diferenças-transatlânticas, expressões-idiomáticas

No Brasil, diz-se que algo é "um saco" quando se fala de uma coisa muito chata, aborrecida. A expressão resvala no baixo calão, mas é bastante utilizada. Em Portugal, entendo que se use "é uma seca" em situações similares.

Dada as similaridades sintática, fonética e gráfica entre as expressões, cogitei que elas pudessem ter uma origem comum, ou que uma tenha originado a outra. Existe esse tipo de relação entre elas?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Nunca tinha pensado nisso. Excelente reatar de actividades aqui na comunidade!

Comment: Obrigado Jacinto! Tenho tido pouco tempo para participar, mas sempre que possível eu passo por aqui :)

Comment: Calculei. E acho que *um saco* deve vir de *encher o saco*, e não tou a ver como é que isso teria a ver com *seca*, embora a existência de *seca* pudesse facilitar a autonomização de *saco*.

Comment: Pois é, ao pé da letra o sentido delas é bem diferente, mas o sentido figurado é semelhante. A dúvida surgiu ao escrever as duas lado a lado a um amigo português.

Comment: Credo, gente. No Brasil, saco vem do ***saco escrotal***. Me parece mais do que óbvio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Uma seca**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/seca) vem claramente do verbo [**secar**](http://www.aulete.com.br/secar), que também significa aborrecer, maçar. Dou pormenores mais abaixo.  A primeira coisa que me veio à cabeça quanto a [**um saco** foi uma relação com **encher o saco** e **ficar de saco cheio**](http://www.aulete.com.br/saco). *Encher o saco* significa aborrecer, irritar, daí a relação.

Entretanto descobri a tese, apresentada sob o título duvidoso de *etimologia falsa*, de que [**um saco** foi cunhado pelos estivadores nos portos brasileiros](https://books.google.pt/books?id=vbidcc_sxXQC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=origem%20da%20express%C3%A3o%20%22um%20saco%22&source=bl&ots=0b24cS6n6_&sig=RhrX3_x8iiTxOg4MRMLrwvAQMr0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBGoVChMIu63z3uDByAIVgcsaCh0J2wEi#v=onepage&q=origem%20da%20express%C3%A3o%20%22um%20saco%22&f=false): uma pessoa chata seria como um saco pesado de carregar. Mais tarde passou-se a usar [**mala**](http://www.aulete.com.br/mala) ou **mala sem alça** com o mesmo significado.

**Saco** é também no Brasil um palavrão com o significado de saco escrotal, e há uma variedade de expressões que parecem aludir a este significado: *chuto no saco* (problema, prejuízo), *coçar o saco* (estar sem fazer nada). Parece-me possível que este significado de *saco* tenha facilitado a sua adoção no sentido de pessoa chata. Há também [a tese](http://revistalingua.com.br/textos/blog-Josue/sobre-sacos-vacas-e-mulheres-nervosas-329845-1.asp) que este significado de saco está na origem da expressão *encher o saco*: o dito cujo ficaria cheio quando uma menina dava conversa, mas não mais que conversa.

**Um saco** poderá ainda ter sido influenciado por **puxa-saco**. Um puxa-saco (todas as definições relacionadas com saco estão no link acima) significa no Brasil um bajulador, lambe-botas, graxista. O consenso na net [(isto é um exemplo)](http://www.dicionarioetimologico.com.br/puxa-saco/) parece ser que a expressão tem origem militar: os soldados rasos carregavam servilmente os sacos de viagem dos seus superiores. Fora do meio militar, um puxa-saco poderá não ter sequer esta utilidade e ser ao mesmo tempo um tremendo saco.

**Uma seca** significa também um aborrecimento, maçada, tédio, ou aquele ou aquilo que causa esse aborrecimento, tédio, etc. Este significado compreende-se bem a partir duma progressão de significados de **secar**. Cito os mais relevantes dos quinze significados apresentados no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa.

> **6** Fazer perder ou perder, vegetais, carne ou peixe, o teor de água neles existente, permitindo a sua conservação. *Nesta região secam sobretudo damascos e ameixas. Os figos secavam ao sol.*
>   **7** Fazer perder ou perder, um vegetal, o viço; tornar ou ficar murcho ou seco.≈ Murchar. *A geada tinha secado os rebentos da videira. As laranjeiras secaram.*
>   **13** Perder a robustez ou o vigor físico. ≈ Definhar, Emagrecer. *A doença fê-lo secar. Depois da morte da mulher, o marido secou.*
>   **11** *Familiar* Aborrecer ou aborrecer-se, alguém, durante um certo período de tempo, devido a ausência de atividade ou a ocupações enfadonhas. ≈ Importunar, Maçar. *Ele secou-me com mil e uma explicações que não interessavam nada. Sequei a tarde toda a ver televisão.*
>   **12** *Familiar* Ficar muito tempo à espera. ≈ Esperar. *Secou duas horas à espera do autocarro (ónibus).*

Passar do significado **6** ao **7** é trivial. Do **7** ao **13** também é relativamente óbvio: uma pessoa que perde vigor, que desfalece, tem semelhanças com uma planta que murcha. Aliás [**murcho**](http://www.aulete.com.br/murcho) significa também sem força, sem ânimo. Do **13** ao **11** também não é difícil de imaginar. Quando alguém nos dá uma seca valente, é como se definhássemos, perdêssemos o vigor. Aqui há talvez uma diferença entre *dar uma seca* e *encher o saco*: *dar uma seca* significa maçar, mas normalmente não *irritar*. O significado **12** é apenas um caso particular de **11**.

A origem de *uma seca* no verbo *secar* parece-me não levantar dúvidas. A origem de *um saco* não é tão clara, mas parece-me provável que seja uma combinação de *encher o saco* até não aguentar mais com o significado de saco escrotal, talvez com a ajuda dos estivadores, sabe-se lá. Portanto parece-me que a expressão *uma seca*, quando muito, poderia ter facilitado o aparecimento de *um saco*: "aquele fulano é uma seca!" "Pior que uma seca, é um saco!"

Answer (score 4):

Não creio que exista correlação entre "*uma seca*" e "*um saco*". "*Um saco*", talvés, tenha tido origem com os imigrantes italianos, pois na Itália usa-se "*che palle*", que pode ser traduzido perfeitamente como "*que saco*".

Answer (score 1):

Não, o saco que a expressão se refere não é o escrotal e a expressão não é chula em sua origem.

No passado algumas cidades brasileiras contratavam pessoas para limpeza de rua, que só terminavam o turno e recebiam a féria do dia quando estavam com o saco cheio de sujeira.

Assim, estar de saco cheio acabou virando sinônimo de saturado, cansado, no limite, exausto, e com o tempo passou a ser usado para qualquer coisa que levasse a essas condições, inclusive chateações do dia a dia: "Já estou de saco cheio dessas músicas, vou para casa!".

Daí para dizer que algo é um saco foi um pulinho: "Esse filme é um saco, chega!".

Comment: Faz muito sentido o q está dito. Poderia colocar alguma referência?